# Java Coding standard: multiple variable declaration

Tags: conventions

Which of the following is best practice according to Java coding standards

```
public void function1(){
    int i1 = 0, i2 = 1, i3 = 2;
    // some code here
}

public void function1(){
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 1;
    int i3 = 2;
    // some code here
}
```

Is there any practice which recommends the usage of first approach, for me its not good for readability but for others in my team it is good practice.

Comment: I have seen both used, but i would say 2nd one as its easier to read.

Comment: which *Java coding standard*? There are an infinite number to chose from. I figure which ever you chose would have this spelled out. any attempt at an answer would be completely off-topic and pure opinion.

Comment: Hundred percent subjective, still for the sake of debugging I always opt to separate lines

Comment: Best practices would recommend to choose better variable names :)

Comment: Best practices would also recommend that no-one answer this question and mark it *"close - opinion based"* instead.

Comment: @X.L.Ant - The real question was with the approach, variable names were picked just to speed up writing question.

Comment: @M-J I know, I was just kidding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not regulate this, it's really a habit, depends on you and your team. I personally believe that 95% of he teams does not prefer this one-line declaration, it's not readable.

Comment: even i m not sure why we got down voted. i'll upvote you two.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I guess this is because your answer is useless, as the question will get closed as opinion based. I saw that happen many times already.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this is what I was looking for, in my opinion I would go for approach 2 since it increases readability. However, I just wanted to rule out any odds.