# Best way to declare variables

Tags: java

I always wonder which is the best way to declare variables and what is advantage of using one over another?

for example

```
private Button stationSearchButton, saveRating, selectDateButton,cameraButton;
```

OR

```
private Button stationSearchButton;
private Button saveRating;
private Button selectDateButton;
private Button cameraButton;
```

Comment: Readability counts. Judge for yourself.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Oracle's Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html) recommend one declaration per line as depicted in your second example.

Comment: It depends. If you need some short helper variables in small scope, like `int i, j, k, m, n;` first approach is better.

Comment: Second one is usually better. If you have too many instances of the same class, you could also find a completely different approach (e.g. array or map).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Coding standard: multiple variable declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930181/java-coding-standard-multiple-variable-declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are speaking about field declaration, not variable declaration (as you have a `private` modifier). It's better to have field declarations one per line. This way you can write independent documentation for each field, add different modifiers in transparent manner like `final` or `transient` modifier or annotations like `@Nonnull`. When speaking about variables (declared inside method body) judge by yourself: it's implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is best, for making your code more compact. With that said, try not to define more than 5 variants with this, because it will become highly unreadable. I recommend using grows declarations in groups, so you can define 5 or less variables on every declaration.

Overall, use multi declarations when it is necessary, and make it easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

Second one approach looks perfect choice, readable, and it is official too.

Comment: Readability and communication should be the primary goal of source code.

Comment: Yes Dave you are correct i just check it out on oracle's Documentation.